# An exercise from Weibel's Introduction to Homological Algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

This question is regarding the exercise 2.3.1. from Weibel's *Introduction to Homological Algebra*.

> Let $d\mid m$ and there is a prime $p$ such that $p\mid d$ and $p\mid\frac{m}{d}$. Then I want to conclude that $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ is not injective over $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.

I know I have to use Baer's criterion.  By the assumption d and $\frac{m}{d}$ are not relatively prime. So there is no injective map from $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Further  Iam not able to. Please help me.

Comment: Since $d$ divides $m$, there *is* an injective map from $\mathbb{Z}/d \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use Baer's criterion here.  Recall that a module $I$ is injective iff for every injective morphism $f: M\to N$ and every morphism $g:M\to I$, there is a morphism $h:N\to I$ such that $h\circ f = g$.

Now consider the unique injective morphism $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, and let $g$ be the one from $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/d \mathbb{Z}$.  Note that, for any morphism $h:\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$, the kernel of $h$ contains all multiples of $d$; note, moreover, that the image of $f$ is the set of all multiples of $\frac{m}{p}$.  Since $p$ divides $\frac{m}{d}$, we get that $d$ divides $\frac{m}{p}$, so the image of $f$ is contained in the kernel of $h$.

Therefore, for any such $h$, we get that $h\circ f=0 \neq g$.  Thus $\mathbb{Z}/d \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be injective.

Comment: What is the unique morphism $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It is the one sending $1$ to $\frac{m}{p}$.

Comment: I have one more doubt. How can we say that for any map h, its kernel contains multiples of d? if x=kd for some k, then how h(kd)=0?

Comment: Because $h(kd)=d\cdot h(k)$, and because $d=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry sorry.. I have asked a very very silly question. thank you so much..